"Package is not visible" error thrown after upgrading the package version
I have a forked out code of lucene 9.10.0 . When I tried to upgrade versions of one of their dependencies org.apache.commons:commons-compress=1.19 to org.apache.commons:commons-compress=1.26.1, i am facing below error during gradle assemble.

C:\apachesolr\lucene\lucene\benchmark\src\java\org\apache\lucene\benchmark\byTask\utils\StreamUtils.java:29: error: package org.apache.commons.compress.compressors is not visible
import org.apache.commons.compress.compressors.CompressorException;

1.26.1 version does have CompressorException class but still I am not sure why this error is shown. Below is the source file looking for package
package org.apache.lucene.benchmark.byTask.utils;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.commons.compress.compressors.CompressorException; //Error thrown by this import
import org.apache.commons.compress.compressors.CompressorStreamFactory; //Error thrown by this import

/** Stream utilities. */
public class StreamUtils {

  /** Buffer size used across the benchmark package */
  public static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1 << 16; // 64K

Entire file -> https://github.com/apache/lucene/blob/releases/lucene/9.10.0/lucene/benchmark/src/java/org/apache/lucene/benchmark/byTask/utils/StreamUtils.java
BTW, I was able to fix this issue by adding an entry "requires org.apache.commons.compress;" in module-info.java, but i am still curious to know why previous versions of common-compress never needed this fix. Am i missing something? Someone please guide thanks.
lucene/benchmark module-info.java -> https://github.com/apache/lucene/blob/releases/lucene/9.10.0/lucene/benchmark/src/java/module-info.java
@SuppressWarnings({"requires-automatic"})
module org.apache.lucene.benchmark {
  requires java.xml;
  requires org.apache.lucene.core;
  requires org.apache.lucene.analysis.common;
  requires org.apache.lucene.facet;
  requires org.apache.lucene.highlighter;
  requires org.apache.lucene.queries;
  requires org.apache.lucene.queryparser;
  requires org.apache.lucene.spatial_extras;
  requires spatial4j;
//Adding "requires org.apache.commons.compress;" here fixes the issue but is it required?

  exports org.apache.lucene.benchmark;
  exports org.apache.lucene.benchmark.byTask;
  exports org.apache.lucene.benchmark.byTask.feeds;
  exports org.apache.lucene.benchmark.byTask.programmatic;
  exports org.apache.lucene.benchmark.byTask.stats;
  exports org.apache.lucene.benchmark.byTask.tasks;
  exports org.apache.lucene.benchmark.byTask.utils;
  exports org.apache.lucene.benchmark.quality;
  exports org.apache.lucene.benchmark.quality.trec;
  exports org.apache.lucene.benchmark.quality.utils;
  exports org.apache.lucene.benchmark.utils;
}

lucene/benchmark module build.gradle -> https://github.com/apache/lucene/blob/releases/lucene/9.10.0/lucene/benchmark/build.gradle
lucene root build.gradle -> https://github.com/apache/lucene/blob/releases/lucene/9.10.0/build.gradle
One more thing, If I use commons-compress versions less than 1.25.0, it is working.

Not sure why you are referring to an older version of the code, but with the latest the requires org.apache.commons.compress; is already existing.

@Naman Thanks for pointing that out, i did not notice that. 9.6.1 solr was not compatible with lucene 9.11.1 because of some code mismatches, that is why i am still using 9.10.0 of lucene as per their release docs.
